# unable to scroll down inside jQuery modal popup when access from my iphone (from a touch screen)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following jQuery code to show a modal popup inside my asp.net MVC core web application:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $(document).on('click', 'button[data-modal]', function (e) {
            $('#myModalContent').css({ "margin": "5px", "max-height": screen.height * .82, "max-width": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load($(this).attr("data-url"), function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    height: 1000,
                    width: 2200,
                    resizable: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    draggable: true
                }, 'show');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

and the following HTML:

```
 <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div id='myModalContent'></div>
           </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

now the modal popup will render a partial view which will show a horizontal tool bar when accessed from normal windows machine (as the partial view has a lot of horizontal content), but if I access the modal popup inside my iPhone then I can not scroll down inside the modal popup. If I try to scroll down, I will be actually scrolling the main page and not the modal popup. Any advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @MosiaThabo yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: Ok Cool, Could you try the answer I provided.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @PedroLudovicoBozzini bootstrap version 4

Answer (score 5):

You can configure this in such a way that when your modal opens, add a class to your `<body>` element to prevent it from scrolling.

On your js, include this where you toggle your modal:

`$(document.body).addClass('modal-open');` Do this when your modal opens
`$(document.body).removeClass('modal-open');` Do this when your modal closes

Then in your css, you can apply some style to that specific class:

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

If you're using bootstrap, you might consider using [checking this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538868/prevent-body-from-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-opened). I am not sure if this is still the case, I'm not familiar with bootstrap.

Comment: i tried your CSS , this have completely prevented scrolling on mobile devices, so if a user open this on mobile browser, they can not see the whole modal popup... previously before adding your code, the user can scroll but will be scrolling the main page and not the popup.. any advice on this further?

Comment: You must add `overflow: auto` on your Modal style. because what the above code does is prevent scrolling on main page... you must still further activate scrolling event on your actual modal container.

Comment: i added this css `body.modal-open {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.modal{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}`.. so i am already adding `overflow: auto`.. is this correct?

Comment: Yes,  That way your modal will add a scrolling effect when the content inside is longer than the display. Try it and give feedback so that I can suggest other approaches.

Comment: as i mentioned i m already adding this css `body.modal-open {     position: fixed;     overflow: hidden;     left:0;     right:0; } .modal{     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto; }.. so i am already adding overflow: auto` , and this will prevent scrolling the modal popup inside the mobile phone, so currently the user can not view the whole popup on the iphone browser, as the modal popup is UN-scrolable ..

Comment: What browser are you testing this on?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881016/4755941) can help you. It sugests the following CSS for a similar problem:

```
body.modal-open {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.modal{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

Comment: i tried your CSS , this have completely prevented scrolling on mobile devices, so if a user open this on mobile browser, they can not see the whole modal popup... previously before adding your code, the user can scroll but will be scrolling the main page and not the popup.. any advice on this further?